# Weird monitor issues related to sleep

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, sleep

About a week ago, the monitor did not return when the system spooled up from sleep.  Actually, the monitor still had a green (connected) lite and when you turned it off, and then back on again i would get a burst of static from the speakers and the monitor logo blinked on and then off.  About 5-10 seconds later, another burst of static and the monitor blinked on for the same half-second this time showing my desktop.  I have an installed graphics card (Nvidia 550 ti) and on-board graphics.  Same monitor behavior from both.  I have a 1000w psu in a Gateway DX4850, intel i5 (second gen) and an Acer monitor.  All drivers updated.  System restore didn't change anything.  If the system sleeps for only a few minutes (<10), then it spools up fine.  Oh, and if you just turn the monitor off and leave it for an hour of so, it sometimes does the same thing, except sometimes it comes back if you click on the screen somewhere.  None of the settings related to power management solve the problem - except leaving the entire system running all of the time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you test the system on a different monitor? Or test the monitor on another PC?

Comment: Wow.  I did not think it was possible that it was the monitor getting flakey; but it was.  Many thanks for the suggestion and for the lesson:  Always try the simple things first and don't over-think!